Numerical sequence 942, 138, 424,?
Homemade number sequence puzzle, quite easy. Sequence: 942, 138, 424, ?

This is pretty straightforward indeed:

 The answer is 68

Why?

 The logic is the first two digits of the previous number are added and the 2nd and 3rd digits multiplied, concatenate the results to make the next number in the sequence… so 4+2 is 6 and 2x4 is 8 making 68.

